# How to disable Woocommerce password recovery and use the default WordPress password reset page?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, password

On my website: https://sciencehook.com/ when I request for password reset, it is redirecting to Woocommerce's reset page: https://sciencehook.com/my-account/lost-password, but I want default WordPress password reset page: https://sciencehook.com/wp-login.php?action=lostpassword

How to do this?

I tried disabling "Reset Password" in Woocommerce settings "Emails" page but it didn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution in WP forum. Here it is:

To remove the WooCommerce redirect for the “Lost Password” link, you’ll want to remove the “Lost Password” endpoint setting as found under `**WooCommerce > Settings > Advanced > Account endpoints**`.

By simply leaving that blank, the user will be forced to use the default WordPress login password reset form